# caml query returns the wrong result,means trying to get today's and upcomming events from query

Tags: javascript, caml-query, sharepoint-calendar

am trying to fetch taday's and upcomming events only from caml query in javascript but it is returning the one event of previous date alsocaml Query is as bellow

```
query.set_viewXml('<View> <Query> <Where> <DateRangesOverlap> <FieldRef Name="EventDate" /> <FieldRef Name="EndDate"/>  <Value Type="DateTime"> <Now /> </Value> </DateRangesOverlap> </Where> <OrderBy> <FieldRef Name="EventDate"/> </OrderBy> </Query></View>');
```

it's result is as like 

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your query returning 1 result from past since you have used not added greater than equals to condition with Today

Try below query:

```
query.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><DateRangesOverlap><FieldRef Name="EventDate" /><Geq><FieldRef Name="EndDate"/><Value Type="DateTime"><Now /></Value></Geq></DateRangesOverlap></Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name="EventDate"/></OrderBy></Query></View>');
```

Comment: sorry that was my fault that i have posted the wrong query which i was trying to see some other result,but now i have changed that in question

Comment: and when am passing the query as you have mensione it returns on theevent of 29th sept(previous dates that current date)

Comment: how many items you have in list ?

Comment: code updated, try this

Comment: see here http://i.stack.imgur.com/hrVnj.png

Comment: as per your screenshot, server time having date as 29th and not 30th. Hence giving only one result for today. ie 29th

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46102/discussion-between-ma6139735-and-gaurravs).